# Echo multiple lines into command?

Tags: linux, bash, echo

It would be very useful for me, if I could do something like this

```
echo {
aic94xx-firmware*
alsa-firmware
btrfs-progs
centos-logos
iprutils
ivtv*
iwl*firmware
} | rpm -e
```

where each package to be uninstall is its own line. This is just one example, but if such a thing is possible in Bash, then I would apply it to other situations too.

**Question**

Is it possible to echo a kind of HEREDOC into a command?

Comment: If we're going for quick and dirty hacks, `rpm -e $(echo ' ... ')` would work (the `...` part can be a multi-line string).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use backslashes to break the command up into multiple lines.

```
rpm -e \
    aic94xx-firmware'*' \
    alsa-firmware \
    btrfs-progs \
    centos-logos \
    iprutils \
    ivtv'*' \
    iwl'*'firmware
```

Or use an array. No backslashes needed.

```
packages=(
    aic94xx-firmware'*'
    alsa-firmware
    btrfs-progs
    centos-logos
    iprutils
    ivtv'*'
    iwl'*'firmware
)

rpm -e "${packages[@]}"
```

Note that either way I've quoted the asterisks. You want `rpm` to interpret the globs, not the shell, so they should be escaped.

Answer (score -3):

You could use `xargs` for this:

```
echo "aic94xx-firmware* alsa-firmware btrfs-progs centos-logos iprutils ivtv* iwl*firmware" | xargs rpm -e
```

Comment: OP meant the packages should be listed on separate lines in his script, not that there should be a separate `rpm -e` for each.